# transpose the output of a sql output using pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a sparksql select query as below

```sql
select max(age),min(age),avg(age),max(sal),min(sal),avg(sal) from Emp;
```

Output dataframe is getting created as below:

| max(age) | min(age) | avg(age) | max(sal) | min(sal) | avg(sal) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 46 | 23 | 31 | 10000 | 2000 | 5000 |

My requirement is the dataframe should be as below using pyspark using transpose.

| columns | max | min | avg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| age | 46 | 23 | 31 |
| sal | 10000 | 2000 | 5000 |

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: How big is the df? can you use pandas?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to run two queries (one for `sal` and one for `age` and `union` them.

```sql
select 'age' as column, max(age) as max, min(age) as min, avg(age) as avg from Emp;
select 'sal' as column, max(sal) as max, min(sal) as min, avg(sal) as avg from Emp;
```

Load those into two dataframes `df_sal` and `df_age` and union them:

```py
final = df_sal.union(df_age)
```

---

Update:
In case only a single query can be done (as commented by the OP). In this case the `stack` method can help you.

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(avg_sal=1, max_sal=1, min_sal=1, avg_age=1, max_age=1, min_age=1)
])

df.show()
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|avg_sal|max_sal|min_sal|avg_age|max_age|min_age|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|      1|      2|      3|      4|      5|      6|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+

(
    df
    .select(F.expr("stack(2, 'sal', avg_sal, max_sal, min_sal, 'age', avg_age, max_age, min_age) as (column, avg, max, min)"))
    .show()
)
+------+---+---+---+
|column|avg|max|min|
+------+---+---+---+
|   sal|  1|  2|  3|
|   age|  4|  5|  6|
+------+---+---+---+
```

In the example I renamed the input columns to avoid problems with brackets in column names. This can be done directly in the SQL query.

Comment: As I have around 1000 columns in my table and I want run a single SQL query. So is there any other way to solve using transpose

Comment: I updated my answer to do the transpose via Spark

Comment: @Satyabrata: did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

If your original dataframe `df` look like below,

```
+-----+------+
|  age|  sals|
+-----+------+
|   46|  2000|
|   23| 10000|
|  ...|   ...|
+-----+------+
```

then

```
org_cols = df.columns
# ['age', 'sal']

sql = spark.sql('select max(age),min(age),avg(age),max(sal),min(sal),avg(sal) from Emp;')

cur_cols = sql.columns
df2 = sql.rdd.flatMap(lambda row: [[org_cols [i], row[3*i], row[3*i + 1], row[3*i + 2]] for i in range(0, int(len(row) / 3))]).toDF(['columns', 'max', 'min', 'avg'])
df2.show()

+-------+-----+----+----+
|columns|  max| min| avg|
+-------+-----+----+----+
|    age|   46|  23|  31|
|    sal|10000|2000|5000|
+-------+-----+----+----+
```